# want to execute a url without loading it in browser in php

Tags: php, curl

Right now i am facing a problem in executing api for sms gateway. They asked me to hit a url and which is http://bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=........&password=.......&mobile=........&message=.......&sender=.......&type=3

but i have to do it without loading this url in a browser. so i used curl method. and where i get a 400 bad request error.It's a windows server with PHP support.

my code is here below -

> $ch = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
>
> $contents = curl_exec($ch);
>
> $ee = curl_getinfo($ch);
>
> print_r($ee);
>
> curl_close($ch);
>
> if ($contents){ echo 'sent'; print_r($contents);
>   }else{ echo 'lost'; }

the $ee returns

> Array
>   (
>   [url] => http://bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=usrname&password=pwd&mobile=9126050xxx&message=Thanking you for ordering through FCI.Your Order will be delivered on time.Your order no is 000198.Please keep it for future reference.&sender=SUBANK&type=3

```
[content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[http_code] => 400
[header_size] => 145
[request_size] => 411
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.094
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.047
[pretransfer_time] => 0.047
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 299
[speed_download] => 3180
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.094
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] =>
```

> )

I think the problem is in the message portion. the space in message in url getting error.because a message without space sent successfully. a &nbsp also is not working.and waht for fullstop(.).please help me in this regards.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your username and password doesn't contain special characters which are reserved in URL. So please convert &,? to their codes like %26 for &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have replace the spaces with %20 and it's works fine for me.thanx for your help everybody...

Answer (score 2):

You should encode the ***message*** query parameter in this way:

```
$message = urlencode("Thanking you for ordering through FCI.Your Order will be delivered on time.Your order no is 000198.Please keep it for future");
```

Here's a ***message*** parameter with right codification to be sent as GET parameter:

> Thanking+you+for+ordering+through+FCI.Your+Order+will+be+delivered+on+time.Your+order+no+is+000198.Please+keep+it+for+future

Answer (score 0):

http://www.technologyworkshops.net/tutorials-f39/curl-using-get-method-with-php-t135.html

```
function curlWithGetMethod($url, $data)
    {
    $fields_string = '';

    foreach($data as $key=&gt;$value){
    $fields_string[]=$key.'='.urlencode($value).'&amp;'; }
    $urlStringData = $url.'?'.implode('&amp;',$fields_string);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlStringData ); 

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}

$data = array('first_name' => 'myname', 'email' => 'example@example.com', 'phone' => '0123456789',  );
echo curlWithGetMethod(''http://www.technologyworkshops.net/', $data);
```